# Fluid responsive layout that controls vertical growth in cells next to an image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a fluid responsive layout with featured content of a single large cell on the left with two smaller cells stacked vertically on the right. I can't post an image here yet, but I can supply [a link to one](http://www.orange-carb.org/~cmh/tmp/stackexample1.png). In the examples you will note that the layout survives having both short and long text in the boxes.

As the browser width narrows, I want to maintain the aspect ratio of the shrinking image, shrink the text column in proportion with the image column, and truncate more of the text given the smaller space. When the layout gets too narrow, media queries would collapse the table cells into three full width rows. (Image above text above links.)

To date I have been able to accomplish what I want on some browsers by absolutely positioning a div holding the text such that it fills a containing display:table-cell div, but this doesn't work on some windows browsers, and produces a disgusting amount of nested divs that I worry will be unmaintainable. However, you can see a demo at http://beta.ckcufm.com that works on Safari 6.1 and Firefox 30.0 on mac. (Some other elements on that page can be ignored.)

I would prefer a non-javascript solution, other than the use of jquery.dotdotdot. Don't need a grid framework, but could use one if it would help.

Comment: Can we have a fiddle for the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Tzcg/

Comment: Would you like to include bootstap.css inyoue code?

Comment: I would like to avoid it given the size. I was thinking perhaps of a smaller grid system (I had my eye on PocketGrid) if that would help. But if there is a solution without that would be even better.

Comment: I used Bootstrap for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mp4bN/4/ Would this work?